# Best way to implement background app on OS X

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, agent

My task is to implement an app working in background which runs some periodical tasks like retrieving current GPS coordinates. At the same time in need to have a status bar icon and menu to give user an ability to do same operations explicitly plus some configuration windows.
My question is if I can use an Agent or should implement this functionality as a Cocoa app without main window?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an Agent to do the background processing and periodic updates. Then have a tiny app to run in the Status Bar, which provides menu options to perform actions or bring up settings. This can use one of the various IPC mechanisms to communicate with the agent.

Another option would be to skip the Status Bar and just have a Settings panel, which can provide both the configuration and have some buttons to initiate certain actions. Depending on how visible the product needs to be, this may be another good option.

Keep in mind that screen real-estate in a user's status bar is precious, and there should ideally be a way to hide the icon if the user doesn't want it. For a n example in the base system, look at how the Bluetooth support is provided. Configuration is all done via Settings, and an optional status bar icon provides quick access.

Comment: Thanks, in this particular case client wants the app to be visible in the status bar at any time when user is logged in.

Comment: To make things even more clear. What stops me from implementing this app as a Cocoa app with LSBackgroundOnly set to YES and start it with launchd?

Comment: Does the background processing need to run even when no user is logged in, or independently of which user is logged in? In that case, you would definitely need a daemon. If it's more an on-demand thing then I guess you could equivalently have a single Cocoa app. Depends on the complexity of the front-end as to which way you lean I guess, and if you ever want the backend to be independent.

Comment: no, application only needs to be active when user is logged in. That's why I don't need a daemon.